# Installing Cordova CLI and Ionic

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, ionic-framework

Recently I installed node.js together with ionic and cordova with:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova ionic
```

... and everything seems to work fine. But when I run:

```
ionic info
```

It seems that Cordova CLI is missing:

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: Not installed
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.0
Ionic Version: 1.1.1
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.10
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
ios-deploy version: 1.8.2 
ios-sim version: 5.0.3 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v5.1.0
Xcode version: Xcode 7.1.1 Build version 7B1005 


******************************************************
Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,      
it is highly suggested to install/upgrade the following:     

Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g 
cordova`

******************************************************
```

I then tried to upgrade cordova as suggested. I also tried to uninstall cordova and reinstall it, clearing the npm cache before reinstallment but after running

```
ionic info
```

...again I still get:

```
Cordova CLI: Not installed
```

Does somebody know the correct procedure to install Cordova CLI?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the end the answer was simple: update cordova to a specific package. I ended up using:

```
npm install -g cordova@4
```

... which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:

Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`

---

Your system information:

```
Cordova CLI: Not installed
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v7.5.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Answer (score 0):

The same problem seems to have reappeared with version 4.2.0.

Running

```
$ cordova telemetry off
```

solved the problem for me. (cordova telemetry on seems to work too)

Details:

```
$ ionic info
******************************************************
 Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:

 Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`

******************************************************

Your system information:

 You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
6.5.0

Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 7
Node Version: v6.9.5
Xcode version: Not installed


******************************************************
 Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:

 Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`

******************************************************


$ cordova telemetry off
You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.


$ ionic info

Your system information:

 ordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 7
Node Version: v6.9.5
Xcode version: Not installed
```