# ionic 2/3 cordova cli commands missing

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Experimenting with ionic, I noticed that not all documented cli commands are visible when one runs ionic --help from project folder.

some cli commands documented [here(Ionic cli docs)](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/) are missing from local setup

```
ionic --help
```

[image: ionic --help output]

Tried all most of the tricks documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598377/error-eacces-permission-denied-ionic-cordova-ios?answertab=active#tab-top) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812254/installing-cordova-cli-and-ionic) to no avail. commands like ionic cordova emulate ios product unable to find command cordova emulate

I have installed ionic@latest which reports v3.4.0 and cordova which reports v7.0.1 (assuming this is latest stable) see images below

```
ionic info
```

[image: ionic info output]

[image: cordova info]

[image: cordova --help output]

Any ideas why cordova command is missing in action from ionic cli commands?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out issue whiles perusing ionic cli project on git. You need to install cordova cli libs (cli-plugin-cordova) too.

```
npm install --save-dev --save-exact @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova@latest
```

Therefore after setting up ionic and cordova globally, you must also run above command in your project.

```
ionic --help
```

[image: ionic --help out put after installing cli-plugin-cordova]